# acrobat pro 9 - how to automatically open video full screen when clicking poster image

Tags: video, adobe-acrobat

I'm using acrobat pro 9 to embed video into a pdf. However, the video, when clicked, plays inside the pdf, and you have to right click and choose open in full screen to get it to play full screen. We have some old pdfs in the office where the video automatically opens full screen, so I know this is possible - does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue - in newer versions of acrobat the default is to use the flash video player. Due to security settings, launching full screen mode is not possible by default. But if you embed a video as a legacy format, launching in full screen is possible in Acrobat 9 (in Acrobat X legacy formats are no longer possible). So, what I did was embed quicktime as a legacy format (Acrobat 6), and in the multimedia properties, under the settings tab, if you click on the rendition and hit edit rendition, under the playback location tab you can specify full screen as the default playback method.